# iFrame video sizing in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a website for my band and am using bootstrap for it.
I want to embed a video into it but I'm running into an issue where it is taking up most of the screen and pushing the NAV options to the side. I want the video to take up the screen up to where the height is not interfering with the NAV options. the Nav items should be centre.

Here is the HTML.

```
  <body class="text-center">

    <div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
      <header class="masthead mb-auto">
        <div class="inner">
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="events.html">Events</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="./Assets/IntroVideo.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: *"pushing the NAV options to the side"* -- I cannot confirm any "pushing to the side" when using your code. So, your question is very unclear right now and it's also unclear what your custom `cover-container` class is doing and why you'd want to slaughter the Bootstrap navbar that way?...

Comment: Try cloning it from github https://github.com/DarkOverNerd/wirefighters.git

Comment: I'd rather suggest this: [mcve] as well as using the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* button when editing your question. That button works quite well.